# htaccess - redirect 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect in htaccess

```
https://www.example.com/albumgallery.php?id=8
```

to    `https://www.example.com/example-gallery`

i've tried :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=8$
RewriteRule ^albumgallery.php$ https://www.example.com/example-gallery? [L,R=301]
```

-- it works , but on page it says

> Not Found The requested URL /example-gallery was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

any ideas what is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a 404 `not found` error because  `www.example.com/example-gallery` does not exist on your server. You need to rewrite this url to your existing url. for example  when you type 
`https://www.example.com/albumgallery.php?id=8` into your browser your rule **redirects** it to **https://www.example.com/example-gallery** since this new url doesn't exist so your server returns a 404 error status. You need to add an internal RewriteRule to your htaccess to handle your new url.

Put the following right bellow your existing Rule

```
 RewriteRule ^example-gallery/?$ /albumgallery.php?id=8&loop=no [L]
```

I added an additional perameter `loop=no` to the Rule`s destination it's to prevent infinite loop error so that the rule can not conflict with your existing RewriteRule.